# Is this redundant phrasing a rhetorical device? Does it have a name?

Tags: phrases, terminology, speech, sentence-patterns

I'm wondering if there's a name for this particular kind of redundant phrasing:

> So what **I'm going to** do right now is, **I'm going to** . . .

or

> So what **you want to do** is, **you want to** . . .

I notice this most often in tutorial contexts (classroom lectures, YouTube videos) or sales pitches.  In a tutorial context, it projects a lack of confidence or knowledge; in a sales pitch, it comes off as a deliberate distraction or verbal confidence trick.

Would this be considered a type of [speech disfluency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_disfluency)?

Note that I'm not asking for a general descriptive word like *circumlocution*.  I'm looking for a name for this specific pattern of speech so I can find out if anything scholarly has been written about it.

Comment: It's not really a rhetorical device is it? I wouldn't say the speaker lacks authority or knowledge either. It's more like a reminder to oneself, a way of echoing aloud one's intentions. Interesting question :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Perhaps you're right that it doesn't reflect a lack of authority or knowledge.  Maybe it's more like mental disorganization.  It's certainly more common when people are thinking while they speak, rather than delivering a rote lecture.

Comment: What is it about this particular phenomenon (of which you've only given us two examples) that you care to capture in a term? Is it the repetition/redundancy? Or is it the lack of planning/poor style? If it is the redundancy, that is not necessarily disfluency (it could be intentional repetition, to fill up time/meter/etc). I ask because there are lots of ways of describing either side (and maybe other sides as well)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a form of *[anadiplosis](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/anadiplosis)*

> (rhetoric) repetition of the words or phrase at the end of one sentence, line, or clause at the beginning of the next

*Collins*

Some might apply the term *[reduplication](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reduplicate#reduplicate)*, although that is more commonly used for repetition within a word.

> Repeat (a syllable or other linguistic element) exactly or with a slight change, e.g., hurly-burly, see-saw.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 1):

How about [pleonasm](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pleonasm)?

> Grammar and Rhetoric. The use of more words in a sentence or clause than are necessary to express the meaning; redundancy of expression either as a fault of style, or as a rhetorical figure used for emphasis or clarity. Also: an instance of this; a superfluously worded expression or phrase.

There are several different types of pleonasm. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) has a comprehensive discussion. Your example would be contextual or stylistic pleonasm.

Answer (score 0):

*So what I'm going to do right now* is a noun clause that functions as the subject of the verb *is* and *I'm going to...* is another noun clause that functions as the complement of the verb "is". This is a perfectly straightforward English sentence, no rhetorical devices required.

Comment: *This* is a stupendously perfect English sentence too, but it exhibits *hyperbole*. Straightforward sentences can still use rhetorical devices.